# Why can't I extract and use many small methods from within my ember-data promise?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my controllers I usually find it's a good idea to name and extract many small methods from a single action if possible. This keeps my method delegating instead of doing + delegating (helps with keeping complexity low / unit testing a method is easier / understanding the scope is much simpler / etc)

But when I'm inside a route and I want to return a promise that is fairly complicated I don't seem to have the same options (ie- I cannot extract many small methods and delegate)

Here is just a quick code snippet to show what I'm talking about

```
App.FindMyThingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        return this.store.find('thing').then(function(response) {
            //now imagine I want to use a mixin or another func from here
            //... but so far that's a no-go
        }
    })
});
```

Is it possible to reach outside of the promise block to share code across your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about keeping a reference to the route instance via a closure:

```
App.FindMyThingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        var route = this;
        return this.store.find('thing').then(function(response) {
            route.usefulMethodFromYourMixin(response);
        }
    })
});
```